# Anagram puzzles

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, anagram

5 independent problems in a "self-help arrangement" (which helps you figure out, what the task is, without presenting an example)

not left + up = honest
tear + boy = jail
five + I = kiln
recursion + maize + confident = recursion
uncommon/back + rage/span = anagram

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this puzzle, you must:

> Find synonyms of the words in each 'word sum', where the letters of those on the left can be combined and anagrammed to make a synonym of the word on the right (or - in one case - the word itself).

Like so...

*not left + up = honest*

> RIGHT + UP --> **UPRIGHT**

*tear + boy = jail*

> RIP + SON --> **PRISON**

*five + I = kiln*

> V + ONE --> **OVEN** (using Roman numerals)

*recursion + maize + confident = recursion*

> I + CORN + SURE --> **RECURSION** (where 'I' is an example of 'recursion' where one is referencing themselves with a pronoun)

*uncommon/back + rage/span = anagram*

> RARE/REAR + ANGER/RANGE --> **REARRANGE**